# Instantiate and initialize "multi-level" maps in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to solve [This problem in BeeCrowd](https://www.beecrowd.com.br/judge/en/problems/view/1049) without using a ton of if/elses.

[image: BeeCrowd problem]

It consists of reading 3 inputs from use, ex:

```
vertebrado
ave
carnivoro
```

and outputting the correspondent word of those inputs.

```
aguia
```

I know more python than java, this would be my solution in python (which works):

```py
dict = {
  "vertebrado": {
    "ave": {
      "carnivoro": "aguia",
      "onivoro": "pomba"
    },
    "mamifero": {
      "onivoro": "homem",
      "herbivoro": "vaca"
    }
  },
  "invertebrado": {
    "inseto": {
      "hematofago": "pulga",
      "herbivoro": "lagarta"
    },
    "anelideo": {
      "hematofago": "sanguessuga",
      "onivoro": "minhoca"
    }
  }
}

word1 = input()
word2 = input()
word3 = input()

word = dict[word1][word2][word3]

print(word)
```

However I'm struggling to code a good solution in Java. This is my current Java solution (which also works):

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Main {
    public static void main (String[]args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String word1 = new String(scanner.nextLine());
        String word2 = new String(scanner.nextLine());
        String word3 = new String(scanner.nextLine());
        
        HashMap<String, HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>> dict = new HashMap();
        dict.put("vertebrado",  new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>());
        dict.put("invertebrado", new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>());
        
        dict.get("vertebrado").put("ave", new HashMap<String, String>());
        dict.get("vertebrado").put("mamifero", new HashMap<String, String>());
        
        dict.get("invertebrado").put("inseto", new HashMap<String, String>());
        dict.get("invertebrado").put("anelideo", new HashMap<String, String>());
        
        dict.get("vertebrado").get("ave").put("carnivoro", "aguia");
        dict.get("vertebrado").get("ave").put("onivoro", "pomba");
        dict.get("vertebrado").get("mamifero").put("onivoro", "homem");
        dict.get("vertebrado").get("mamifero").put("herbivoro", "vaca");
        
        dict.get("invertebrado").get("inseto").put("hematofago", "pulga");
        dict.get("invertebrado").get("inseto").put("herbivoro", "lagarta");
        dict.get("invertebrado").get("anelideo").put("hematofago", "sanguessuga");
        dict.get("invertebrado").get("anelideo").put("onivoro", "minhoca");
        
        
        String word = dict.get(word1).get(word2).get(word3);
        
        System.out.println(word);
    }
}
```

The obvious issue with that solution is that it's unpractical to populate the dict that way. The code is already big. If `dict` had a lot values, with a lot of "depth", it will become a hell to maintain.

Is there a way to reduce it? IE, declaring and initializing `dict` in a couple of lines?

Comment: depends on how you store the data that should be contained in `dict`. Looking at you python example, you pretty much have a JSON which you use as input. You can do the same in java. Provide a JSON file with the desired data and depth and read it in java. [How to read JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31743324/7109162)

Comment: That would be perfect for this example @XtremeBaumer! I'll search about transforming a JSON into a dict, thanks!

If it happens that the final key were Java variables/functions, would that work too?

Comment: Well, since Java 9, there is the `Map::of` method, which allows to trim down your code a little.

Comment: Searching about `Map::of` , thanks @MCEmperor!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Map.of() as MC Emperor suggested:

```java
Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>> dict = Map.of(
    "vertebrado",
        Map.of(
            "ave",
                Map.of(
                    "carnivoro", "aguia",
                    "onivoro", "pomba"
                ),
            "mamifero",
                Map.of("onivoro","homem",
                        "herbivoro","vaca"
                )
        ),
    "invertebrado",
        Map.of(
            "inseto",
                Map.of(
                    "hematofago", "pulga",
                    "herbivoro", "lagarta"
                ),
            "anelideo",
                Map.of(
                    "hematofago","sanguessuga",
                    "onivoro","minhoca"
                )
        )
);
```

Compared to using a `json` file this also gives you type checking as you go, although to be really type safe you would want to introduce classes named `Phylum`, `Class` and `Order` to wrap your Strings, instead of leaving values "Stringly typed".

Comment: This will only work till 3rd level of parent right ?

Comment: Yes, which is correct for the domain as modelled -- if you try to access data which isn't there you will get a compile time error, likewise you can't fail to completely construct the tree without typing a `null`.

Comment: If you were modelling down to Family level you'd declare your `Map` with an extra level.

Comment: I discovered Map.of() has a limitation of 10 entries, you need to use Map.ofEntries to use unlimited entries which is more verbose :c